# I have 3 questions?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

First, if I have a customObject object__C, and it's in a look up relationship with the Lead object. How do I make an object__c for all leads meeting certain criteria? This seems pretty straightforward to do with:

```
for(list<string> lead :[SELECT id FROM Lead WHERE Criteria = 'TRUE']) {
Object__c OBJ = new Object__C(Name = 'name',lead=lead.id);
insert OBJ; 
}
```

But is that the only way to do something like this, without creating custom apex code each time? Should I make a Visual Force page to perform the search and insert the object__c's?

Secondly, I would like the have 3 versions of Object__C with different fields depending on a picklist value. Again would this be a visual force page? Can this be done?

and Finally, how do I store a string only used in a schedulable class, but it can be updated by a user on the fly?

Comment: Two things. First, please stick to one question per question. Second, try to use a title that actually summarizes what you'd like to ask.

Comment: Sorry, should I delete and make three questions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Apex is not following best practices and is likely to trigger limits errors by including DML operations in a loop. If you need to populate this object only for existing records, use a data loader. If you need to populate for newly-created or populated records, use a properly bulkified Apex trigger or Process Builder depending on the level of complexity of the object and your expected data volume (higher => Apex).
2. Record Types is the functionality you need
3. Custom Labels provide this functionality.

Comment: bulkified apex trigger means trigger that calls a batchable class? I need all three versions of the object__C to be available to the users.

Comment: Bulkification is a standard Salesforce design pattern. It is covered in the [Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_bulk) module on Trailhead.

Answer (score 0):

Your apex code is not correct and you are inserting in for loop you will get DMLException definitely.

your code should be like this

```
    List<Lead> lstlead = [SELECT id FROM Lead WHERE Criteria = : 'TRUE'];
    List<Object__c> OBJ;
    for(lead l : lstlead ) {
       Object__c OB = new Object__C(Name = 'name',lead =l.id);
       OBJ.add(OB);
     }
     if(OBJ.size()>0){
         insert OBJ;
    }
```